# Reputable web based ssh client?

Tags: ssh

I'm connected to a coffee shop's wireless network right now, and I suspected I'd be able to use my laptop and ssh somewhere. Unlucky me they seem to be blocking everything but web traffic (my testing seems to show everything but port 80 is working, can't ping, ftp, etc).

I googled "web based ssh clients" however I have reservations about entering my login credentials on any Joe Schmoe's web app. I was wondering if anyone has had any experience with any reputable web based ssh clients? If so could you please point me at one that I could trust?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming you don't need access right this minute, you might try running a copy of SSH on port 80 or port 443 as to avoid that restriction in the future. I used to do that from an old VPS.    Though, if you're up against a local caching proxy, that might not help.

Comment: thanks but I don't actually control the server, it's a server administered by a hosting company.

Comment: I honestly wouldn't trust any third party SSH service w/ my credentials. If there isn't one on your control panel, I'd fork over the $20/mo for a utility VPS and just do it myself.

Comment: @Doug ...so install it on a machine you *do* control. I run sshd on port 443 on a machine at home, and have it update its hostname via DynDNS. This lets me get past most restricted networks.

Comment: +1 to Gerald. Having a box that runs no other services just so you can ssh from is a useful thing to have anyway and worth setting up. Assuming you don't run a web server from your home to the outside world you could even port forward incoming connections to 443 on your home router to port 22 on your server.

Answer (score 5):

Your best option is to run Shell In a Box on **your own server**. http://code.google.com/p/shellinabox/

I've used this and to be honest it's unbelievable good. It's scales to your browser size and running apps like vim and alpine work really well.

You can run it via SSL for extra safety.

Answer (score 1):

I am mostly using http://webssh.uni.me/ when I'm somewhere else (or with https if the firewall allows it).
Before 'really' using it i created a test-account that couldn't run anything dangerous on my system and couldn't read write any of my data.
I used that user on the site, waited a couple of days, checked my logs and could only see 1 login (mine) so now I'm pretty sure it's safe (Although i still only use web-based ssh clients when there is nothing else available).
I would suggest testing the website you want to use like that.

Answer (score 1):

[Commando.io](https://commando.io) is a web based SSH interface. It supports writing commands *(called recipes)* in `shell`, `bash`, `perl`, `python`, `ruby`, `go`, or `node.js`. They also just released scheduling, which allows you to automatically run commands on servers periodically in a cron like fashion via a centralized web-interface.

Answer (score 0):

You're already willing to enter your credentials via your laptop in a coffee shop. I'd think of using some sort of vpn, or ssh tunnel.

You can actually get what you need by using some clever nat and port forwarding rules on a device somewhere on the internet. I'll give you more details if your interested. If there is a http proxy then you wont be able to get much through it. You may get some success with this

http://dag.wieers.com/howto/ssh-http-tunneling/

There quite a lot of wireless mischief you can be exposed to on unsecured wireless access points.

If your doing a lot of ssh stuff, perhaps think about a mobile wireless connection from a cell/mobile provider.

Answer (score -3):

You're already willing to enter your credentials on a random PC in a coffee shop. Through either malice or incompetence, you can bet that PC is compromised in some way.

Comment: The pc is not random. It is my laptop. I'm connected to the coffee shops wireless and need to do some work.